# Vertically center overlay window

Tags: facebook, overlay, center, vertical-alignment

For an application I am working on, their is a requirement for a custom overlay to display detailed information about a selected item. I am using jQuery Tools for this but am having issues centering the overlay vertically within the user's viewport. Because the page is so tall it is rarely in an appropriate location (either to high or to low). How can I force this overlay to be centered?

Answer (score 0):

You can indeed center the overlay with jQuery Tools. They were kind enough to include this functionality. If you read the source it has a conditional check for if the option key "top" has the value of "center"

Thus,

$(".overlay").overlay({
 top: "center"
});

And that's it!